# MSSQL - duplicate records based on id while having two primary keys

Tags: sql-server

Title might be misleading. I'm using MSSQL database server.

What I want to reach - I want to have duplicate records based on different languages.

For instance, I've column `*language*` and column `*id*` - both primary keys.

Result I want:

```
id    lang     name
1     English  x
1     Foreign  y
```

How to reach this? MSSQL doesn't let me insert values with same id.

I have read in forums that it isn't possible, but then again, I've an example of real existing structure using MSSQL:

[image]

One solution I did find was - set Identity specification to *no*. I'm not sure this is the best approach. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a `COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY` which is a `PRIMARY KEY` made from `two or more columns`.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
  id INT,
  lang char(200),
  name char(200),
  primary key (id, lang)
);
```

You can refer to [this document](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys.aspx) for more understanding on Composite Primary Keys.

**Edit** :

For Editing/Altering the exiting Table, you can do something like this :

```
ALTER TABLE  MYTABLE 
DROP CONSTRAINT PK_Table1_ColID

ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Table1_ColIDLANG PRIMARY KEY (id, lang)
```

To explicitly insert values in identity columns, do something like this :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MYTABLE ON;

/* Do inserts */

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MYTABLE OFF;
```

Comment: Well, yes, both id and lang is primary keys (set), but it doesn't let me insert  record with same id, even though language values are not the same. I already have table with data, so I can't use statements like create ect., so if you can, please try to give answer for existing table - editing design properties.

Comment: Check the Edit.

Comment: Well, for double-check, I took off all primary keys and added constraint. Everything was successful, but when I try to insert

INSERT INTO x(id, lang, name)
VALUES 
(404,'ru', 'Jiang'),
(404,'en', 'Jiang');

I get - Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'x' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: Identity column will be auto-incremental and hence you can insert values into it explicitly but now you can have duplicates as the primary key is composite.

Comment: If you want to do your own inserts, do `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Table_Name ON;`

Answer (score 0):

Use id and lang as composite primary key, so combination of these two attributes must be unique :

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
        id int not null,
        lang varchar(30) not null,
        name varchar(50),
        PRIMARY KEY (id, lang)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `id` field set as identity, then it will automatically put a new value in that column for every row. This is what it means to be an identity column. So if you actually want some repeat values, you will need to set identity to no. Then when you insert, you can insert any value you like into that column.

If you want to have the identity functionality, but choose what to insert as well, you can use the `identity insert` function:

```
set identity_insert [tablename] on;
insert into [tablename] (id, lang, name) values
(1, 'English', 'x'),
(1, 'Foreign', 'y')
set identity_insert [tablename] off;
```

You will also be able to use the composite primary keys as suggested in the other answers.

Comment: The example I mentioned higher, has identity specification on. So there must be an alternative